# Two methods with the same behavior

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

### The goal

Create two "different" methods with the same behavior.

### The problem

When someone accesses my application, I want to display a list of items — and this list is the same provided by `myapp.com/products/offers/`. In other words, I don't want to repeat the same code between the two methods. ***So I ask: what do I have to do?***

### What I'm doing now

At `HomeController`, on `Index` method whose its type is `ActionResult`, there is the following code's fragment:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return RedirectToAction("Offers", "Products");
}
```

Meanwhile, at `ProductsController`, on `Offers` method:

```
public ActionResult Offers()
{
    var products = Products.Build.OffersList();
    var categories = Categories.Build.Main();

    ProductsViewModel viewModel = ProductsViewModel
    {
        Products = products,
        Categories = categories
    };

    return View(viewModel);
}
```

Now there are three things to consider:

1. My application is redirecting the client to another page, generating a second server request wasting bandwidth;
2. The URL of application is changed from `myapp.com/` to `myapp.com/Products/Offers/` and I really don't want this;
3. Will be redundant if I repeat the code — further more that there are things in the `ProductsController` that by logic should not exist on `HomeController`.

And, again: ***What do I have to do?***

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Move the common logic into a "Service" or "Helper" class:

```
class ProductListingHelper {
    public ProductsViewModel GetProductsViewModel() {
       var products = Products.Build.OffersList();
        var categories = Categories.Build.Main();

        return new ProductsViewModel() {
            Products = products,
            Categories = categories
        };
    }
}
```

Then, in both of your controllers, do this:

```
 return View(new ProductListingHelper().GetProductsViewModel());
```

Note, that, as Erik points out in the comments, this will require you to create two Views. However, you can also reduce duplication here, by having your ProductListView as a Partial View that the other two views render.

Comment: Also I'd mention that is requires two views unless you do additional work (easy enough but not mentioned).

Comment: Two identical views? Seriously? oO

Comment: @GuilhermeOderdenge Not entirely. The controller's may have different logic.. the common stuff is moved into a helper. Also, the views may be slightly different. However, by moving the common product listing into a partial view, you can change the surrounding views independently, whilst keeping the product listing common between them. Notice the question just says "here is some duplicate logic between actions, how do I reduce the duplication?". It doesn't specifically mention they will be identical.

Comment: Thanks, @SimonWhitehead, but I found a (temporarily?) solution: make the `View()` method search on `Products` folder by default. I don't know if this is a good practice or a good behavior for performance terms, but avoids redundancy. Have you an opinion about this?

Comment: That entirely depends on the requirements of your application. You may find changing default behaviour like that troublesome later on.. but performance wise, it is no different to how the Views are searched by default anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Add a class (usually referred to as a 'Service' class) and move the code you want to reuse into a method in that class (perhaps call the method `GetProductsViewModel()`) then call that method from each of your controller actions.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I was not looking over the shoulder of @SimonWhitehead <grin>